# go make friends

Tags: vocabulary

> "You'll soon find out some wizarding families are much better than others, Potter. You don't want to **go** making friends with the wrong sort. I can help you there." 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I don’t find an idiom of *go make friends*. Then what does go mean in this contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, "go" is sometimes place in front of a verb to indicate that the person should take action. It can indicate the difference between taking initiative and being passive, or it may simply be used for emphasis.

"You should go make friends" is very similar in meaning to "You should make friends." But there is the subtle distinction that the first implies you need to get off your chair and take action, while the second could be understood to be passive, that is, that you might sit back and wait for people to come to you.

"You should go run a mile" and "You should run a mile" are also very similar. As running presumably implies taking action in either case, the only difference here is emphasis.

Comment: There is another difference, as well. Americans normally say things like "You should go run a mile" but British people don't. They normally use the word *and* or *to*, after the word *go*. In the UK, your example would be "You should go **and** run a mile".

Comment: Americans also say "go and", so if there's a difference, it's that Americans say both "go run" and "go and run", while Britons only say "go and run". I don't think there's a difference between "go run" and "go and run" in practical meaning.

Comment: Jay, I think you're right. It's a difference in use.